# Hiding/Removing StatusBar in Flutter (on button click)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, statusbar

In my app when button clicked, I want statusBar to be absolutely hidden.

I've already tried  `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);` and  `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`
it makes statusBar black but it still takes space on top of the screen.

So how can I make statusBar disappear fully when I click specific button?

Comment: [Similar Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);` works fine, the remaining space you are seeing is just the `AppBar`. You can change the size of the `AppBar` at the same time you hide the status bar, by wrapping it in a [`PreferredSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) widget and setting the size property to a variable that you change with [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) when the button is pressed.

[image: Status bar hidden and AppBar resized]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  double appBarHeight = 55;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight),
          child: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Hide Status Bar'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
                setState(() {
                  appBarHeight = 35; // After status bar hidden, make AppBar height smaller
                });
              },
              child: Text("Hide Bar"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT: TO HIDE STATUS BAR, NAV BAR, AND THEIR RESERVED SPACES**

To hide both status bar, navigation bar, and the spaces that are reserved for them like this:

[image: Remove status bar, navigation bar, and spaces]

You can get rid of both using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);`, then set your AppBar to `null` using a `bool` and `setState`, and set the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property of your scaffold to `false`.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool showAppBar = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: appBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
              setState(() {
                showAppBar = false;
              });
            },
            child: Text("Hide Bar"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  appBar() {
    if (showAppBar) {
      return AppBar(
        title: const Text('Hide Status Bar'),
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am removing appBar when button clicked (I am setting appBar to null). So I think AppBar is not the reason of this space. Also NavBar also leaving the space do you know hot to remove that space?

Comment: @SardorbekRkh I spent a long time investigating your issue, and found a solution. Please refer to my edit. I hope it helps.

Comment: In my case, empty space left by statusBar was caused because of SafeArea, after removing this, everything worked, but removing SafeArea is bad for iOS devices with notch, however I solved it somehow. Thank you for cooperation

Answer (score 3):

In [Flutter 2.5](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-5-6f080c3f3dc), you would do this using the following snippet:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
```

You can use any of the following [SystemUiMode enums](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiMode-class.html):

- immersive
- immersiveSticky
- edgeToEdge
- leanBack